# Addition: $10,000+9,999+9,998\cdots$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there a math equation to solve:  $10,000+9,999+9,998\cdots+1$?

Would $10,000\times5,000$ be the answer. I thought of this through $10,000+0=10,000$  $9,999+1=10,00$0.... etc.  All the numbers added with there opposites add up to $10k$.  There are $5,000$ of these I believe - $10,000/2 = 5,000$

Comment: In that order: yes, and no. Your reasoning is almost right.

Comment: Almost! The only thing that's missing is that $5000$ doesn't have a partner. So it's $10000 * 5001 - 5000$. The general formula is $1 + \cdots + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, for exactly the reasons you've shown. (EDIT: thanks Thomas, off-by-one errors are the worst)

Comment: You can't add $5,000+5,000=10,000$, so that over-counts by a bit.

Comment: Those two formula don't agree, @HenrySwanson. Your first formula gives $9999\cdot 5000$. Hint: There are $5000$ numbers in the set $0,1,2,\dots, 4999$.

Comment: Wait I don't see.  If 5,000 is being counted twice don't you subtract one not add one????

Comment: So you're adding pairs of the form $0 + n$, $1 + (n-1)$, etc, that all sum to $n$. If $n$ is odd, there are $\frac{n + 1}{2}$ pairs (don't forget to count $0$), and nothing left over. So you have $n \cdot \frac{n+1}{2}$. If $n$ is even, you have $\frac{n}{2}$ pairs, with the number $\frac{n}{2}$ left over. So that's $n \cdot \frac{n}{2} + \frac{n}{2} = (n + 1) \frac{n}{2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The consecutive sum of numbers $1$ through $n$ is

$$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

Applying this to your problem yields

$$\frac{10000(10000+1)}{2}$$

Comment: Thanks!  Looks like I was close, just didn't subtract by one.

Comment: I misinterpreted the question, I thought there was a minus sign in front of the $10000$ term, please see my edit!

Comment: hmm I thought I understood it before lol.  Because 5,000+5,000 is counting 5k twice you -1.  But if that was wrong how does it work???

Comment: Try out the equation for small $n$, say $n=4$, so the sum is $1+2+3+4 = 10 = 4\cdot5/2$. If you want to avoid using the formula see Henry Swanson's answer above.

Comment: Oh I see now, 2+3=5 which is 1 more than 4

Answer (score 3):

There is a well known formula that:
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
Your expression $10000+9999+9998+\dots + 1$ can be rewritten as $1+2+3+\dots +10000$. This can be written in summation notation as:
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{10000} i$$
Using our formula:
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{10000} i=\frac{10000(10000+1)}{2}$$
$$=5000(10001)$$
$$=50005000$$
So $10000+9999+9998+\dots +3+2+1=50005000$